# why is kses removing semicolon from inline style?

Tags: php, validation, wp-kses

I have a validation function that uses `wp_kses`, and it works as expected to remove code from the input if it is relatively simple code HOWEVER using kses is also removing semicolons from inline styles. (in `<h1 style="color: red;">the name</h1>`, the semicolon after the word 'red' is removed)

Documentation makes no mention of this behavior, is it a bug?  My actual code using kses is below.  Can anyone tell me how to change my code so that kses does not remove the semicolon?

```
function sanitize_name($valid, $value, $field, $input) {

    if( $valid !== true ) {
        return $valid;
    }

    $allowed = array( 
        'h1' => array(
            'style' => array(),
        ),
        'h2' => array(),
        'h3' => array(),
        'h4' => array(),
        'h5' => array(),
        'h6' => array(),
        'p' => array(),
        'br' => array(),
        'strong' => array(),
        'b' => array(),
        'em' => array(),
        'ul' => array(),
        'li' => array(),
        'ol' => array(),
        'div' => array(),
        'span' => array(),
        'pre' => array(),
        'button' => array(),
        'svg' => array(),
        'blockquote' => array(),
        'a' => array(),
        'i' => array(),
        'sup' => array(),
        'sub' => array()
    );

    $value2 = wp_kses( $value, $allowed );

    
    if ( strcmp( stripslashes( $value ), $value2) !== 0 ) {
        return 'Please remove the disallowed HTML from this field to submit.<br />
        Entered:' . stripslashes($value) . '<br />
        Cleaned:<br />' . $value2;
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

Comment: Semi-colons are not required after a single declaration.

Comment: @vancoder I believe that is true, however as you can see, my next step is a `strcmp` which gives a false negative because of the missing semicolon.  Do you know of a way around that?

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't the missing opening quote on the style attribute? I don't think this is a kses problem, this is a HTML mistake

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be mixing validation and sanitation in the same function, right now there's a problem that the check doesn't escape or sanitise its own outputs to make sure the error message is safe to display, and there's no way for the code that calls this function to know if sanitising worked or failed because you can't validate without also sanitising. It also means late escaping is impossible because unsafe HTML is being returned. There should be a separate `validate_name`

Comment: @TomJNowell
The test input is `<h1 style="color: red;">Photo Challenge 1</h1>` and the output is `<h1 style="color: red">Photo Challenge 1</h1>` or `<h1 style="color: red; text-decoration: underline;">Photo Challenge 1</h1>` and `<h1 style="color: red;text-decoration: underline">Photo Challenge 1</h1>` so there is no HTML mistake that I see.  The last style attribute doesnt have the semicolon on both...  Is that a bug with `wp_kses`?

Comment: just going on what was in your question which has the missing quote. Make sure you edit your question to include all the necessary information and that it's accurate with no mistakes. Also `wp_kses` does not modify the HTML you give to it, it breaks it apart, removes the parts that do not match the whitelist, then rebuilds it into a new HTML fragment, there's no seeking through the full string and snipping things out. https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c7f6abe9f44413b1864f84073e5acd74a9a1cb64/wp-includes/kses.php#L1325 is responsible for the attributes

Comment: Also what's the reason for needing to try and preserve the semicolon that lead to this question? Keep in mind that many would actually consider this a feature not a bug

Comment: @TomJNowell yes you are absolutely correct, my question had a mistake in it and that may have thrown you off so I apologize for that but it is fixed now.  The reason I do want to preserve the final semicolon if it appears in the inline style is only so that the proceeding `strcmp()` will work and the error check that prevents form submission will be fired.  I compare the original string to a new string built by runnning the original string through `wp_kses()` and if they are the same then there was no unallowed code in the string and everything is ok to go forward...

Comment: @TomJNowell BUT if the strings are different that means there was code that was removed and an error is thrown/submission is not allowed.  I'd be happy to use another solution, but this is the one I thought of and I think it would work if not for this little feature of `wp_kses()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no signs that this was accidental or a bug, and has been in core for many years. This is because of this set of lines at the end of the main loop of `safecss_filter_attr`:

```php
            // Only add the CSS part if it passes the regex check.
            if ( $allow_css ) {
                if ( '' !== $css ) {
                    $css .= ';';
                }

                $css .= $css_item;
            }
```

The root of the question is a broken assumption that `wp_kses` modifies the original HTML string, which is not the case.

Instead, `wp_kses` uses regular expressions to break apart your HTML into arrays which are then further subdivided by more regular expressions. It's these arrays that are then going to be processed to remove attributes and tags etc. Then these are reassembled to create a brand new HTML string.

Comment: I am trying to show an alert when code was removed and disallow the field to be submitted hence the `strcmp()`, however I am getting a false negative and the strings are different whether kses removed code or not.  Clearly the `strcmp` is not allowing this to happen, so how can I achieve that?

Comment: interesting, you should ask a new question about that, if I left an answer for _that_ question here it would be incredibly confusing to anybody who came here since that's not what your original question was asking. Also you're falling into the X Y problem trap, except it looks more like an X Y Z problem here, you should ask how to solve your problem, not how to fix your solution, in this case there's multiple layers as your check + `alert` combination is also a solution to an unnamed problem. Would it not be easier to add a HTML class? Inline styling is an anti-pattern